# Python typing support for NamedTuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Please check the below code

```py
import typing
import abc


class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> typing.NamedTuple[typing.Union[int, str], ...]:
        ...


class NT(typing.NamedTuple):
    a: int
    b: str


class B(A):

    def f(self) -> NT:
        return NT(1, "s")


print(B().f())
```

I get an error. In parent class `A` I want to define method `f` such that I indicate that any child class should override it by returning a `NamedTuple` that is made up of `int` ot `str` fields only.

But I get a error sayin that:

```
TypeError: 'NamedTupleMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

Changing the signature as below helps but then how will I tell typing system that the child class can return NamedTuples's that have only int and str's

```py
class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> typing.NamedTuple:
        ...
```

Comment: Can't you use `NT` as the type in class `A` as well?

Comment: @Dan presumably, though, OP would want to be able to use `class Foo(NamedTuple): bar: int` and then that wouldn't work

Comment: Now, I'm not particularly well read on type systems, but how would a static type checker make use of this? If all you know is that it is some type that has some number of attributes which are `typing.Union[str, int]`, you'd still have to complain about `foo.bar` because that type doesn't know about bar...

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that fundamentally `typing.NamedTuple` is not a proper type. It essentially allows you to use the class factory `collections.namedtuple` using the syntax of inheritance and type annotations. It's sugar.

This is misleading. Normally, when we expect:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    pass

foo = Foo()
print(isinstance(foo, Bar))
```

to always print `True`. But `typing.NamedTuple` actually, through metaclass machinery, just makes something a descendant of `tuple`, exactly like `collections.namedtuple`. Indeed, practically its only reason to exist is to use the `NamedTupleMetaclass` to intercept class creation.  Perhaps the following will be illuminating:

```
>>> from typing import NamedTuple
>>> class Employee(NamedTuple):
...     """Represents an employee."""
...     name: str
...     id: int = 3
...
>>> isinstance(Employee(1,2), NamedTuple)
False
>>>
>>> isinstance(Employee(1,2), tuple)
True
```

Some may find this dirty, but as stated in the Zen of Python, *practicality beats purity.*

And note, people often get confused about `collections.namedtuple` which is itself not a class, but a class factory. So:

```
>>> import collections
>>> Point = collections.namedtuple("Point", "x y")
>>> p = Point(0, 0)
>>> isinstance(p, collections.namedtuple)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Although note, the classes generated by `namedtuple`/`NamedTuple` *do* act as expected when you inherit from them.

Note, your solution:

```
import typing
import abc


class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> typing.Tuple:
        ...


class NT(typing.NamedTuple):
    a: int
    b: str


class B(A):

    def f(self) -> NT:
        return NT(1, "s")


print(B().f())
```

Doesn't pass mypy:

```
(py38) juan$ mypy test_typing.py
test_typing.py:18: error: Return type "NT" of "f" incompatible with return type "NamedTuple" in supertype "A"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

However, usint `Tuple` does:

```
class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> typing.Tuple[typing.Union[str, int],...]:
        ...
```

Although, that may not be very useful.

What you *really* want is some sort of structural typing, but I can't think of any way to use `typing.Protocol` for this. Basically, it can't express "any type with with a variadic number of attributes all of which are `typing.Union[int, str]`.